# Set a value deep in a dict dynamically

Tags: python

If I have a nested dict `d = {'a':{'b':{}}}` and a string `'a.b.c'` and a value `'X'`

I need to put the value in the dict based on the key string.

What I want to achieve can be hard coded as `d['a']['b']['c'] = 'X'` but I need to do it dynamically. The keystring could be of any length.

For bonus points: I also need to create keys if they don't exist like `'a.b.z'` but I'm sure I can figure that out if I can work out the case where they already exist.

Comment: In your own words, what are the key steps in this process? What part don't you think you can do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
def set(d, key, value):
    dd = d
    keys = key.split('.')
    latest = keys.pop()
    for k in keys:
        dd = dd.setdefault(k, {})
    dd.setdefault(latest, value)

d = {}
set(d, 'a.b.c', 'X')
set(d, 'a.b.d', 'Y')
print(d)
```

Result:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': 'X', 'd': 'Y'}}}
```

Comment: Great use of `setdefault`! This trumps my implementation by MILES, if only for the lack of recursion. I always forget it returns the value it sets -- took me forever to figure out how you were nesting.

Comment: This is awesome! Why do you use `dd` inside the function? What would break if you used `d` directly? Just curious...

Comment: You're right. There is no reason. It work without a temp var.

Comment: If you want `value` to be set even when a previous value already exists, change the 2nd `setdefault` call to `dd[latest] = value`.

Comment: If you pass `keys` as a list to the function instead of splitting a string on periods, you can use any kind of datatype in the key path, say `set(d, ['foo', 'bar', 42], value)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def recursedict(d,keylist,value=None):
    key = keylist.pop(0) # removes and returns the first key
    if len(keylist): # True if there are more levels to go down
        try: assert type(d[key]) is dict
        except KeyError: d[key] = dict()
        except AssertionError: raise ValueError("d[{}] is a {}".format(key,type(d[key])))
        # if d[key] doesn't exist, make it a dict()
        # if d[key] DOES exist, and isn't a dict, raise a KeyError

        recursedict(d[key],keylist,value)
        # recurse
    else:
        if value is None:
            return d[key]
        else:
            d[keylist[0]] = value
            return value

def setdeepdict(d,attributestr,value): # double entendre intentional
    keys = attributestr.split('.')
    recursedict(d,keys,value)

def getdeepdict(d,attributestr): # double entendre SUPER intentional
    keys = attributestr.split('.')
    recursedict(d,keys)
```